# form submit does not work after moving div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in which I have placed my textarea with submit button. I need to put the textarea under the each post to let the user post comment.

Here is the shape of my textarea

```
<div id="textarea_wrap">
   <div id="textarea_12" class="txtarea">
   <form name="post_comment" action="reply.php" method="post"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="post_title" value="Post Title" />
   <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="12455" />
   <textarea class="textarea" id="txt_12"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit Comment />
   </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I get the innerHtml of div textarea_wrap and move it to some other div using Jquery, it stops working.

For example

```
  var txtarea = $("#textarea_wrap").html();
  $("#comment_10").html(txtarea);
```

It moves the `textarea_wrap` div's inner html to `#comment_10 div` successfully and when I view the source after moving div using jquery it looks like this

```
<div id="comment_10">
   <div id="textarea_12" class="txtarea">
   <form name="post_comment" action="reply.php" method="post"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="post_title" value="Post Title" />
   <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="12455" />
   <textarea class="textarea" id="txt_12"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit Comment />
   </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

But it does not work, when I click on the 'Submit Comment' Button, nothing happens. If I use this code without moving through jquery, it works fine. Can't understand that why it is not working after moving through jquery.

Comment: are you using any javascript /jquery to submit your form

Answer (score 2):

Given that the form which have cloned has the same name as before, this creates an error in the DOM when you try to submit the form.

**Suggestion:** Change the form name every time you clone it.

**Solution(jQuery):**

*From*

```
var txtarea = $("#textarea_wrap").html();
$("#comment_10").html(txtarea);
```

*To*

```
var txtarea = $("#textarea_wrap").html();
$("#comment_10").html(txtarea).find('form').attr('name','post_comment'+(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure though..check to see if you can submit it like this

```
$('.button').live('click',function({
    $('#give your form Id').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both forms have same name "post_comment". Form name should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not be a part of the issue, but you have a syntax error in your submit button definition. Remember to close the quote for the value attribute **value="Submit Comment**